# How to append a file to multiple files in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a TXT file that I need to append at the bottom of multiple files.
I'm currently using for loop for that :

```
for file in file1 file2; do cat footer.txt >> $file; done
```

Any other commands I can use instead?

Answer (score 3):

The tee command allows you to apply changes to several files at once.

```
tee -a file1 file2 < footer.txt
```

Will do it. The -a tells tee to append on the end.

Comment: Thanks! Makes it much easier